# Add fragments to pageviwer once one has finished?

Tags: android, listview, networking, asynchronous

I am currently creating an RSS reading app, which uses the page viewer....so that the user can swipe between different views/feeds within the app.

The problem is, is that the app freezes once I swipe to the second view...due to it trying to load too much data all at once.

So I am asking if there is a way of adding each view, once the previous view has been loaded; or anything really to make the application load the data without freezing, and to make it load smoother.

Any help will be great! Thanks.

This code is how I am adding the views:

```
        package com.example.directrssread;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class ViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

           /** maintains the pager adapter*/
        private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
            //initialsie the pager
            this.initialisePaging();
        }

        /**
         * Initialise the fragments to be paged
         */
        private void initialisePaging() {

            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed1.class.getName()));

            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed2.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed3.class.getName()));
            //fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Feed4.class.getName()));
           // fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
            this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter1(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
            //
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        }

    }

This code is from one of my views (they all have the same code, and there are 4 of them)

    package com.example.directrssread;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Feed1 extends ListFragment{

    String[] URL = new String[3];
    int count = 0;
    String currURL = "";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed1, container, false);

        }

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // rssRun();

         boolean runSubstring = true;
            //URL[0] = "http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/a/arsenal/rss.xml";
            URL[0] = "http://talksport.com/rss/football/premier-league/feed";
            URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            URL[2] = "http://talksport.com/rss/football/premier-league/feed";

            //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            for (int f= 0;f < URL.length;f++)
            {

            try{
                 //Log.e("TEst1", "TEst");

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            //Log.e("XML", xml);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
            // looping through all item nodes <item>

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                if (doc!=null)
                {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    currURL = "Football365";
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    currURL = "BBC Sport";
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    currURL = "TalkSport";
                }


                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                //Get the title of the article.
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                //Get the description of the article.
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                //Get the source e.g ' Football365'.
                //String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                //Parse the date and time from the main strings.
                //Chop off the un-wanted parts.
                //Bring them back together in one string.
                String pubTime = pubDate.substring(17, pubDate.length());
                pubTime = pubTime.substring(0, 5);
                pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, 16);         
                pubDate = pubDate + " " + pubTime;
                //Log.e("TITLE", )      
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, currURL + " - " + pubDate);          
                //Add the link.
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                //Get the publish date.
                //map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
                Log.e("TEst", "TEst");
                for (int q = 0;q < map.size();q++)
                {
                    Log.e("mene", map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                }


                }

            }
            count+=1;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            }

            // Adding menuItems to ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
            //if (count==3)
            //{
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            //}

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();
            //TextView firstName = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            //EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            //ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l)
            //ListView lv = ((ListView) findViewbyId(R.id)

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
        }



         Log.e("RUN", "RSSRUN");
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         }



     public void rssRun()
        {
            boolean runSubstring = true;
            //URL[0] = "http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/football/teams/a/arsenal/rss.xml";
            URL[0] = "http://talksport.com/rss/football/premier-league/feed";
            URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            URL[2] = "http://talksport.com/rss/football/premier-league/feed";

            //URL[3] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
            for (int f= 0;f < URL.length;f++)
            {

            try{

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            //Log.e("XML", xml);

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            //Log.e("NODELIST", nl.toString());
            // looping through all item nodes <item>

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                if (doc!=null)
                {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    currURL = "Football365";
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    currURL = "BBC Sport";
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    currURL = "TalkSport";
                }


                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                //Get the title of the article.
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                //Get the description of the article.
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
                //Get the source e.g ' Football365'.
                //String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                String pubDate = parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE);
                //Parse the date and time from the main strings.
                //Chop off the un-wanted parts.
                //Bring them back together in one string.
                String pubTime = pubDate.substring(17, pubDate.length());
                pubTime = pubTime.substring(0, 5);
                pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, 16);         
                pubDate = pubDate + " " + pubTime;
                //Log.e("TITLE", )      
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, currURL + " - " + pubDate);          
                //Add the link.
                map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                //Get the publish date.
                //map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
                for (int q = 0;q < map.size();q++)
                {
                    Log.e("mene", map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                }


                }

            }
            count+=1;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            // Adding menuItems to ListView
            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC,KEY_LINK, KEY_TITLE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.link, R.id.source});
            //if (count==3)
            //{

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                  });
                }
              }).start();


                //setListAdapter(adapter);
            //}

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                    String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                    in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });
        }
        }


    /*protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.feed1);
           ////initialsie the pager
           //this.initialisePaging();
       }*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practise to do time consuming tasks in activity life cycle methods. Instead you should use loaders alongwith your fragments. The loader can load the data in the background and meanwhile you can show a progress dialog. Once the loading is completed in loader you can display the data in your fragment.
This will make the UI responsive. 
Read more about loaders from here

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html

Comment: Sure let me know if you have any query